# How do I loop over the creation of multiple data frames in pandas in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd 

FB = financialReturns[financialReturns['ticker'] == 'FB']
AAPL = financialReturns[financialReturns['ticker'] == 'AAPL'] 
NFLX = financialReturns[financialReturns['ticker'] == 'NFLX']
TSLA = financialReturns[financialReturns['ticker'] == 'TSLA']

CompanyReturns = pd.DataFrame()

for x in CompanyNames2Use:  
    CompanyReturns[x]=financialReturns[financialReturns['ticker'] == x]
```

From https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jK5L7dWmAqbih9CG1wenj9WvBNaR7R_n#scrollTo=AI2j9cQ_njXt

In `financialreturns`, there are columns with the labels of 'FB', 'AAPL', 'TSLA', and I want to split up this giant `financialReturns` dataframe into 4 different dataframes of 4 different labels.

Comment: If the below solutions helped, please consider accepting it (green tick on the left), so other users know. Or, of course, feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary for this:

```
d = {k: df[df['ticker'] == k] for k in ('FB', 'AAPL', 'NFLX', 'TSLA')}
```

Then you can access each slice via `d['FB'], d['AAPL']`, etc.